# Bitbucket pipeline ipv6 VPS

Tags: bitbucket, vps, bitbucket-pipelines

I've got a problem. I want to use pipelines on BitBucket to deploy to my VPS whitch is ipv6. My .yml is exactly like this:

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: 
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://[xxxx:xxxx:x:x::xxxx:x]:21/exmaple_dir.com/
```

Bitbucket is still throwing this err:

```
fatal: Can't access remote 'ftp://usrname:***@ftp:', exiting...
```

I think that I just wrote ipv6 badly, but Im not sure.. can you help me please?
Im running SFTP and I can connect with FileZilla with no problems.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

SFTP is FTP wrapped in SSH, so it uses port 22. Does your host respond properly from Pipelines on that port?